# Get blobs in a virtual folder on azure (BlobService.ListBlobs) (C#)

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, azure-storage

I am working with Azure Storage and I am programming in C#. I have a container all setup on Azure, I am able to save files into virtual folders inside our container.

However I am having trouble accessing blobs inside virtual folders inside my container. For example say i have:

container1/virtualfolder/file1.png

I want to be able to list all the blobs (such as file1.png, etc...) inside virtualfolder. How can I reference only these files? I have tried using BlobServices.ListBlob but it returns everything in the container. I have tried to modify the container path but it returns "BadRequest". I think this is an issue with path.

Here is my code:

```
    public void getBlobOffServer()
{
    string resourcePath = "container";
    StartCoroutine(blobService.ListBlobs(getBlobListComplete, resourcePath));
}

private void getBlobListComplete(IRestResponse<BlobResults> response)
{
    if (response.IsError)
    {
        Debug.Log("FAILED" + response.StatusCode + response.ErrorMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < response.Data.Blobs.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(response.Data.Blobs[i].Name);

        }
        isComplete = true;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` of `GetDirectoryReference` to get all blobs from virtualfolder.

```
string containerName = "container-1";
string directoryName = "virtualfolder";
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(directoryName);
var blobList = directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null).Result;
foreach (var blob in blobList.Results)
{
       Console.WriteLine(blob.Uri.OriginalString.Substring(blob.Uri.OriginalString.LastIndexOf('/')+1));
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]